# Failed to reconnect to my previous account

Tags: support

I was trying to reconnect to my account **RLF** after being absent for a year or so.  But what I actually did is create another ***RLF** account.  (Sigh)  I would like to be reconnected to my previous 4 years, 3 months account.

I would like to reconnect to my former account which is **user:26626**.